# Using Fatou's lemma to show that $u_n \rightarrow u$ and $\int u_n < \int u$ not possible for $u_n\geq 0$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $u,\, u_n \in \mathcal{L}^1(\lambda)$ such that $u_n \rightarrow u$

I want to show that with $\int u\,d\lambda=6$ and $\int u_n\, d\lambda=4$ for all n then:

Is it possible achieve for all $u_n \geq 0$?

My conclusion is, that it is not possible. I am using Fatou's lemma such that:

$$\int_\mathbb{R} u\, d\lambda = \int_\mathbb{R} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} u_n\, d\lambda \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_\mathbb{R} u_n\, d\lambda$$

However it strikes me that this is not allowed because it is the limit of integrals

Any hint would be appreciated

Comment: You made a good job, but some details are missing. First, it's not true that $\lim_{n\to \infty }u_n=u$. Nevertheless, this is correct up to a subsequence (why ?). Then, you should argue why $\liminf$ are really $\lim$, and why you can use Fatou's lemma. When all these task will be done then your proof will be complete.

Comment: Isn't the argument that $\forall n:u_n\geq 0$ and because $u_n\rightarrow u$ (assumption) then $\lim u_n=\liminf u_n=u$?

Comment: It's not true that $u_n(x)\to u(x)$. What you have is $u_n\to u$ in $L^1(\mu)$, nothing better. The argument to use Fatou's lemma is only $u_n\geq 0$, but recall that Fatou's lemma says $$\int \liminf_{n\to \infty }u_n\leq \liminf_{n\to \infty }\int u_n$$ whenever $u_n\geq 0$ for all $n$, not that $\int \lim u_n\leq \lim\int u_n$.

Comment: Your $u_n\rightarrow u$ stands for the $L^1$-convergence while $\lim_n u_n$ stands for the pointwise convergence. They are different. But when you have an $L^1$-converging sequence you can pick up a pointwise-converging subsequence and apply Fatou's lemma to that subsequence. This is what Surb means.

Comment: @HyeongmukLim When you write $\mathcal{L}^1$ convergence, do you mean that $\int u_n \rightarrow \int u$? 

If I have $u(x)=5x$ and $u_n(x)=5x-\frac{1}{n}$ then $u_n \rightarrow u$. In my textbook (Schilling) it does not mention anything about $\mathcal{L}^1$ convergence

Comment: Sorry, I think I wrote the definition incorrect :( I have edited the description now. I think it must be a pointwise convergence assumption in the homework because it states that the integrals are 6 and 4 respectively, thus $u_n \rightarrow u$ can only be meant to be the pointwise convergence. So I think the subsequence is assumed

Comment: @Daniel: $u_n\to u$ in $L^1$ means that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty }\int|u_n-u|=0$.

Comment: Sorry, it was probably my mistake to presume you meant $u_n\rightarrow u$ in $L^1$. If you meant pointwise convergence then your solution using Fatou is utterly correct.  Convergence in $L^1$ is defined the way Surb described, by the way.

Comment: Thanks, I learned something new that we also define convergence only for the integral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That it is impossible can be easily seen from

$2=\int ud\lambda - \int u_n d\lambda  \leq  \int |u-u_n| d\lambda \rightarrow 0$,

which is absurd. Note that the last convergence follows from the definition of convergence in $L^1$-norm.