# Existence of positive sequence of measurable functions

Tags: measure-theory, limsup-and-liminf

Consider the measure space $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B} (\mathbb{R}),\lambda)$. Let $u \in L^1(\lambda)$ such that $ \int_{\mathbb{R}}^{} u \,d\lambda\ =3$.

I am trying to find out whether it is possible to find a sequence of functions $u_n \in L^1(\lambda) $ that converges to $u$ such that $ \int_{\mathbb{R}}^{} u_n \,d\lambda\ =1$ and $u_n \geq 0 $ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

$\
$

My intuition tells me that the answer must be no. I have tried explaining it mathematically by Fatou's lemma.

If such a sequence $u_n$ is to exist, we know by Fatou's lemma that the following inequality holds:

$ \int_{\mathbb{}}^{} \lim_{n \to \infty} inf $ $ u_n $ $ \,d\lambda\ \leq \lim_{n \to \infty} inf \int_{\mathbb{}}^{}  $ $ u_n $ $ \,d\lambda\ $

$\
$

But we find that: $\
$

$ \int_{\mathbb{}}^{} \lim_{n \to \infty} inf $ $ u_n $ $ \,d\lambda\ = \int_{\mathbb{}}^{}  inf $ $ u $ $ \,d\lambda\ = \int_{\mathbb{}}^{}  $ $ u $ $ \,d\lambda\ = 3 $

$\
$

And: $\
$

$ \lim_{n \to \infty} inf \int_{\mathbb{}}^{}  $ $ u_n $ $ \,d\lambda\ = \lim_{n \to \infty} inf $ $ 1  =1 $

$\
$

Hence the inequality does not hold which tells us that such a sequence does not exist. Is my arguing here correct? And is the conclusion correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Fatou's lemma to show that $u_n \rightarrow u$ and $\int u_n &lt; \int u$ not possible for $u_n\geq 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3375649/using-fatous-lemma-to-show-that-u-n-rightarrow-u-and-int-u-n-int-u-not) (don't read the "answer", which is wrong because of a misunderstanding of the question, but read the end of the comments: approval of your proof)

Comment: I think that approves my solution. Thank you.